# My SparkSession initialization takes forever to run on my laptop. Does anybody have any idea why?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My SparkSession takes forever to initialize

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession
         .builder
         .appName('Huy')
         .getOrCreate())
sc = spark.SparkContext
```

waited for hours without success

Comment: It might happen when any other spark job is running in background and the current job is not getting its required resources. Have you checked that ?

Comment: see here [SPARK-20352](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20352?jql=project%20%3D%20SPARK)

Comment: Could you fix it? @To Huy

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I have resolved it by setting the environment variables. We can set them directly in python code. You need a JDK in the program files.

```html
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "C:\Program Files\Spark\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop2"
```